# Backbone.js - Value is not passed from a view to another view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

When I try to pass **entry** variable from one view to another view, I'm getting entry is undefined in the second view.

This is my posts View

```
append_post: function(post){        
    view = new Stream.Views.PostEntry({entry: post});
    $("#stream-bank").append(view.render().el);
}
```

This is my post entry view

```
Stream.Views.PostEntry = Backbone.View.extend({

  template: JST['streams/post'],

  render: function(){
    console.log(entry); // Error: 'entry is not defined' 
    this.$el.html(this.template({post: entry}));
    return this;
  }
});
```

Comment: You've accidentally (I hope) created a global variable by not saying `var view` inside `append_post`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backbone handles some arguments to the constructor by assigning them to properties of this (see View#initialize for details), the rest go into this.options. 
                                                                 - mu is too short

```
render: function(){
    console.log(this.options.entry); //  
    this.$el.html(this.template({post: this.options.entry}));
    return this;
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `this.options.entry`?

Comment: When I do this.entry, post is undefined. But this.options.entry works! thanks!

Comment: @Srikanth: Backbone handles some arguments to the constructor by assigning them to properties of `this` (see [`View#initialize`](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor) for details), the rest go into `this.options`.

Comment: @muistooshort why dont you add your comment as answer so you get credit for this answer?

Comment: Or you can fix your answer, I'm happy as long as Srikanth has things sorted out.